# Start/stop fixed position HTML JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position

I have a `div` which is positioned: relative and then when scrolled down it will become fixed. However, the start is good but I can't seem to get the code work in a way that it would start from one point and stop at another point.

Here is an example from AirBnB.

https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/13402355?s=9uSqc8q_ (Right handside booking)

Maybe some of you have it done already? I would really appreciate your help!

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cyfb6s8t/1/

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Share your code so far.

Comment: Share your code here, or create a JSFiddle.. How do we know which part of your code that doesn't work

Comment: Will do that, I'm still a noob at @stackoverflow... https://jsfiddle.net/cyfb6s8t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a class called "fixed". That's not in your CSS that you linked.

Also, you could consider just using the .css() to make a few modifications: .css("position": "fixed", "top": "0", "left": "0")

I believe that would work.

Comment: Have you tried it without #book.fixed, rather just .fixed?

Comment: Yes, not much luck... the best thing is that this solution that I currently have works right for the first point, but then I have tried multiple ways of trying to add the second point but just doesn't work...

Comment: The goal obviously is to write JS or JQuery so that once you reach a certain point scrolling, you override several selectors and get your element to stick on the page. Go through each step (debug), and work from the ground up. Start with printing in your console the current scrolling position. Make sure this is working and that you can access this value before moving on. This is a good way to make sure you know what is going on and that you're doing it correctly. Good luck and update me on your progress!

Comment: Thanks Jadon, I found some good scripts which perform similar to what you have pointed out! Thanks again. :)